# Compile Coffee Script in parallel

Tags: javascript, compilation, parallel-processing, coffeescript

How can I make `coffee` compile, when compiling directory tree of many `.coffee` source files, distribute the work across all processors?

**UPDATE** I'm not interesting in linking of any kind, what I'm looking for could run in parallel for sure.

Comment: Are each `.coffee` files processed independently, or is there linking happening too?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about your compiling process and expectations? Are you trying to write a node.js parallel compiler, are you attempting to run parallel `coffee -c` jobs from shell or something totally different?

Comment: @ShadowWalker Yes I'd like to `coffee -c` to run a bit faster, and because it doesn't do any linking, it just produces "parallel tree" of .js files, then why is it utilizing single thread?

Comment: I am not sure spawning multiple node processes to compile coffee files in parallel would be a performance gain, especially for a larger number of coffee files (>30)...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `find . -name \*.coffee`
do
    coffee -c $f&
done
```

Comment: As @ShadowWalker implied in comments, this is slow.

Comment: It's probably still faster than compiling them one by one, on a 4+ core machine. I wouldn't be surprised if the bottle neck was the speed of your harddrive.

Comment: I would like to see an actual performance measurement of both scenarios to have something significant to back our proposals up. I feel that the node-based compilation would be faster. Anyone interested in writing the tests...?